# Using GEOS API functions in C lang returns segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, geos

I am trying to use some libgeos (https://github.com/libgeos/geos) functions from my C program. Below is my code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <geos_c.h>

int main() {

    GEOSContextHandle_t ctx  =  GEOS_init_r();

    GEOSGeometry *inputGeom = GEOSGeomFromWKT("MULTIPOLYGON (((30 20, 45 40, 10 40, 30 20)), ((15 5, 40 10, 10 20, 5 10, 15 5)))");

    printf("%s\n", GEOSGeomToWKT(inputGeom));

    GEOS_finish_r(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is that I'm getting a segmentation fault when I run the binary. Below is the gcc command that I used to compile the program.

```sh
gcc -g -Wall geos.c -o geos -lgeos_c
```

Please see below the gdb output.

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/srimal/proj/src/geos/geos 
warning: the debug information found in "/lib64/ld-2.27.so" does not match "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" (CRC mismatch).


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:62
62      ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S: No such file or directory.
```

I would be really grateful if someone can help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you check that: `inputGeom != NULL`?

Comment: Debug your program step by step, check the return values and where exactly SIGSEGV occurs. You should extend your code to check all return codes. Can `GEOSGeomToWKT` return `NULL`? Maybe you should check the result before using the value in `printf`.

Comment: Yes. I have added that condition.

Comment: Thanks all. Finally, the code is working. :) I have posted the fixed code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. I should have used `initGEOS` and `finishGEOS` functions. Below is the correct answer with some improvements.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#include <geos_c.h>

void notice(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    fprintf( stdout, "NOTICE: ");
    va_start (ap, fmt);
    vfprintf( stdout, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    fprintf( stdout, "\n" );
}

void log_and_exit(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    fprintf( stdout, "ERROR: ");    
    va_start (ap, fmt);
    vfprintf( stdout, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    fprintf( stdout, "\n" );
    exit(1);
}

int main() {

    initGEOS(notice, log_and_exit);

    GEOSGeometry *inputGeom = GEOSGeomFromWKT("POINT (30 10)");

    if (inputGeom == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "NULL GEOM");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("%s\n", GEOSGeomToWKT(inputGeom));

    finishGEOS();
    return 0;
}
```